# Splitting sound inputs between left and right channels in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, audio, mixer

is there any way of assigning specific line-in feeds to one side of a speaker system, using freeware/opensource software?

I have, 3 computers, A and B have output from their headphone sockets to each of the line-in ports on the back of computer C, is there anyway to tell computer C to feed the sound from A and B, to the left hand speaker, and the sound from itself to the right hand speaker?

The supplied as standard realtec audio driver has individual controls for both line-ins, and main sound, but no way of splitting the output between left/right channels.

Using windows 7 on computer C, xp on computer B, and linux/whatever on computer A.